# Previous and Next Implementation on UIView with animation effect

Tags: ios, ipad, ios5.1

I am working on an iPad application, displaying `TableView` listing according to returned data from server (Json parsing). I want to implement a `DetailView`, that will show the tapped row's detailed information. For that I am using a `UIView` in the same listing class. It gets alpha 1.0 to visible and alpha 0.0 for hidden. This `UIView` is loaded with a custom class nib (uiview type).

I want to add next/previous functionality to view other `TableView` listed records.

Could anyone please suggest the best way for doing that? For now I am trying to have a scroll view but it will not create many pages (using content size), I should animate like scroll but same page need to update either previous or next record. All data records I have are in the array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Implement the solution.
I just add two SwipeGesture to the detaileview (For LeftSwipe and rightSwipe). Initially this detail view is hidden but when  cell taped it get appears with the data from the Arraydata at the index table row index. I manage the RowIndex value initially get from the table row taped
. When user Left swipe or right swipe the RowIndex either increased or decreased by one and accordingly updated data from aaray shown on the view.

Thanks